# definition of weak*-weak* continuous

Tags: analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading a paper and I have  couple of terms which I can't seem to find the definition for, the first one

1) what do we mean by weak*-weak* continuous map.

2) what is the definition of  a left translation invariant subspace.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: 1) It must be a typo, which is meant to be weak-$\ast$ continuous. 2) This is usually when a space is acted upon by group : A subspace is translation invariant if $g\cdot W \subset W$ for all $g\in G$

Comment: Or it could refer to the [weak* topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_topology#The_weak-.2A_topology)

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan, thank you, but I don't think the first one is a typo it appears in the statement of several theorems in the paper.

Comment: Regarding 1), I'm almost sure it means a map $X'\to Y'$ that is continuous when both $X'$ and $Y'$ are endowed with the weak$^\ast$ topology.

Comment: @DanielFischer , is this the same as saying $T$ is weak*-weak* continuous if we have $x_n\to x$ in weak* then $Tx_n\to Tx$ weak*.

Comment: No, that is the same only if sequences are enough to describe the weak* topoology.

Comment: @GEdgar , how about if I changed the sequence to a net will it be alright then?

Comment: Yes, nets are enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,

1. A map $f:X\to Y$ is "topology 1"-"topology 2" continuous if it is continuous as a map from $(X,\text{topology 1})$ to $(Y,\text{topology 2})$. This can be described by preimages of open sets, or by nets: if $x_\alpha \to x$ in the sense of topology 1, then $f(x_\alpha)\to f(x)$ in the sense of topology 2.
2. A left translation invariant subspace is a subspace that is invariant under left translation. Which begs the question: what is left translation? I think your space is some space of functions on a group $G$, in which case left translation by $g\in G$ is the operator that transforms $x\mapsto f(x)$ into $x\mapsto f(gx)$. Example: the space consists of continuous functions on the circle $\mathbb T\subset \mathbb C$, and $g =i $. The space of functions $f$ such that $\int_{\mathbb T}f=0$ is invariant under left translation by $g$ (or by any element of $\mathbb T$ for that matter).

Comment: Thank you, Yes the space i'm asking about is a subspace of $L_\infty (G)$.